# How to make an input to accept only two decimals and have maximum of 10 digits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, restrictions

How to make an input to accept only two decimals and have maximum of 10 digits?

I use a function that is activated at `onkeypress` and gets the length of the value inserted in my input. I got to make it to accept max 10 digits, and maximum of 2 decimals, but after I put those 2 decimals, I can't introduce any other number. For example if I have 1234.11, I can't make it to 10234.11.

```
function onlyNumbers(){
if($('#GoalQuestionValue').val().toString().length>10) return false;
if($('#GoalQuestionValue').val().indexOf('.') != -1 && $('#GoalQuestionValue').val().toString().length-$('#GoalQuestionValue').val().indexOf('.') >2) return false;    
}
```

Comment: do you mean that before `.` must be max 10 digits
and after `.` should be max `2` digits?

Comment: @MaveRick max 10 digits = 8+2decimals

Comment: try keyup and keydown functions instead of onclick or onchange.

Comment: I think you have to check in keypress listener for digit input.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onlyNumbers(){
var n = $('#GoalQuestionValue').val().toString().split('.');
if(n[0].length > 8 || n[0].length < 2) return false; else return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "onclick" try to use events "onchange" or "oninput".
If you are talking about algorithm, I think this is the best one:

```
function onlyNumbers() {
    var myArray = $('#GoalQuestionValue').val().toString().match(/([0-9]*)\.?([0-9]*)?/);
    if(myArray[1]) {
        if(myArray[1].length > 10)
            return false;
        if(myArray[2]) {
            if( myArray[2].length > 2 )
                return false;
            if( myArray[1].length + myArray[2].length > 10)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it's on 'onkeypress' sorry. I modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regex to validate this requirement:

`if($('#GoalQuestionValue').val().toString().match(/[0-9]{8}\.[0-9]{2}/)!=null && $('#GoalQuestionValue').val().toString().length>11)`

Answer (score 0):

try keyup and keydown functions instead of onclick or onchange.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check in `keypress` listener for digit input -

```
$("#GoalQuestionValue").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) {
        if (!isValidNumberStr(this.value)) return false;
    }
})
```